# Getting extra enter characters from jquery's ajax respond

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have MVC architecture for my project and recently I got a weird problem. Whenever I try to respond the Ajax request with printing some output in PHP, I get 8 enter characters before my output. I noticed that it's putting these characters when just I want to echo but I don't know how these extra enters come when they're not in the string that I try to output. I've checked all of my files encoding to make sure that they aren't the problem. I even left the response empty to check whether there is some script earlier printing something or not but it wasn't, the output was empty without any character.

Is there any tip?

Here's my js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _baseRoot + '/admin/request',
    type: 'post',
    data: "req=" + req + args,
    success: function(data)
    {
      var result = data.split(",");

      var m_type = "";

      switch(result[0])
      {
        case "error": m_type = "red"; break;
        case "warning": m_type = "yellow"; break;
        case "success": m_type = "blue"; break;
      }

      showMessage(m_type, result[1]);
    }
  });
```

Comment: The extra characters are coming from your server, giving us your javascript isn't going to help unless you wan't to modify your response with javascript to get rid of them.

Comment: I actually did! I trimmed the data with jQuery's $.trim. I know this is a problem of mine but I really don't why it comes at printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really pinpoint it without seeing the backend, but as as most php project goes, those are probably comes from various included files that doesn't mean to output anything but has a `?>` and a newline at their end. The php interpreter just simply passes everything to the output that is not inside the `<?php ?>` tags.

If you don't want to output anything from a php file, you can remove closing `?>` and the interpreter simply detects the end-of-file as the end-of-script, and it makes sure that no accidental whitespace creeps into the output from after `?>`.

Comment: Thanks. I think this make sense because I recently added some spaced tags in my files with exactly an enter char. I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I wasn't really be aware of that!